# jQuery slideup and down feature delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a few images with a `div` and header on it that when mouse entering it slides up and leaving vise versa. It works, however the slidedown doesn’t happen right away. So, if I hover the mouse over it a few times quickly (lets say 10 times) it will slide up and down for like 30 seconds. I know there is something wrong in my code. Any ideas?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.indexgall').on('mouseenter',function(){
        $(this).addClass('hoverimg');
        $(this).children().animate({
            top:150
        },600,function(){
        });
    });

    $('li').on('mouseleave',function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hoverimg');
        $(this).children().animate({
            top:250,
        },600,function(){
        });
        $(this).stop().animate({});
    });

}); // END DOCMENT READY
```

```
.hoverimg
{
    box-shadow: .2% .2% .2% gray;    /*2px 2px 2px gray */
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1sypzt2f/)

Comment: Please post your HTML, and a jsfiddle would be helpful :)

Comment: You have to use `.stop()` for animated children. BTW, `$(this).stop().animate({});` doesn't make much sense

Comment: JSfiddle posted :) and i took out the (stop) but same thing.

Comment: Why not just use the `:hover` psuedo-class in CSS?

Comment: You folks should be using [stack snippets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animations queue up when called on the same element. You should call `.stop()` before you call `.animate()`.

```
$(this).children().stop().animate({
```